# retrieve image url from firebase storage to database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app allows for Facebook authentication. When the user logs in, I will like to set up a node called users that holds some of the user's information.Specifically, I will like to get the user's UID, name and profile picture from Facebook.

Here is my code so far:

```
    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

    // using the credentials above, sign in to firebase to create a user session
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        print("User logged in the firebase")

        // adding a reference to our firebase database
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://gsignme-14416.firebaseio.com/")

        // guard for user id
        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }

        // create a child reference - uid will let us wrap each users data in a unique user id for later reference
        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)

        // performing the Facebook graph request to get the user data that just logged in so we can assign this stuff to our Firebase database:


        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil).start{
            (connection, result, err) in


            if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{
                let name = user.displayName! as String


                let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                let data: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage!, 0.5)!
                let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
                let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com")
                let profilePicRef = storageRef.child(user.uid+"/profile_pic.jpg")


                let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"

                // Upload the file
                let uploadTask = profilePicRef.put(data, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in
                    if (error == nil) {

                        self.downloadurl = metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

                    } else {

                        print("there was an error uploading the profile pic!")


                    }


                let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                    "uid": uid,
                    "username" : name,
                    "userpic" : self.downloadurl


                ]



            if ((error) != nil) {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                print("fetched user: \(String(describing: result))")

                let values: [String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]

                // update our database by using the child database reference above called usersReference
                usersReference.updateChildValues(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    // if there's an error in saving to our firebase database
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!)
                        return
                    }
                    // no error, so it means we've saved the user into our firebase database successfully
                    print("Save the user successfully into Firebase database")
                })
            }
                }}}


    }
```

Without implementing retrieving the user's photo URL from firebase storage, it works perfectly by outputting the name and UID. However, when I try to retrieve the image URL from firebase storage it crashes and nothing outputs. I am not really sure what I am doing wrong.

I want the database to look like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the procedure how to upload image in storage and update link of image in DB and then how to retrieve image from link.**

Update data in DB.

```
 //// **NOTE:** store user ID globally in user auth so that you use userID here
func updateUserData(){
        let dbstrPath : String! = "\(userid)"// where you wanted to store Db.

        // Create dict as your DB.   
        let aDictUpdateValues = ["userName"       : "John",
                                 "userEmail"      : "john@gmail.com",
                                 "userPic"        : "",
                                 "uid"            : userid] 
        // The Db is created as per your dict and file path. So create this two things specifically according to you..
        dbRef!.child(dbstrPath).updateChildValues(aDictUpdateValues, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

            if error == nil{
                print("updated successfully")
                self.uploadProfilePic()
                dbRef.child(dbstrPath).setValue(aDictUpdateValues)

                let aData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: auserDetail)
                print(ref)
            }
            else{
                print("error in updation")
                print(error!)
            }
        })
    }
```

// Upload image in storage

```
 func uploadProfilePic(){
        var data = NSData()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ivProfile.image!, 0.8)! as NSData
        // set upload path
        let filePath = "\(userid)" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        self.storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{// store imageURL in DB.
                let dbfilePath = "\(userid)/userpic" // update db userpic link.
                //store downloadURL
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
                //store downloadURL at database
                dbRef.child(dbfilePath).updateChildValues(["userPic" : downloadURL])
            }
        }

    }
```

Get image form firebase storage.

```
 func getProfileImage(){
          let dbstrPath : String! = "your_db_path" // path where link is stored in  DB.
        dbRef.child(dbstrPath).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

          // get dict of value from db.
            if let aDictValue = snapshot.value! as? [String : Any] {

                // call storage ref from link
                 self.storageRef =  FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: aDictValue[Constant.FireBaseDBKey.kuserProfilePic]! as! String)
                // Assuming your image size < 10MB.
                self.storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 10*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                    if data != nil{ // if image found 
                        let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.ivProfile.image = userPhoto
                    }
                    else{ // if img not found set default image.
                        self.ivProfile.image = UIImage(named: "profile")
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```